# How to search by string

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core-mvc

My website can show the data now.
I want add a function which can search string with  Primary key.
How do I create a search option for my website?
Can sb send the teaching paper for me? I have read it. but I still have no idea.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-5.0.
and also I have try this way. But I do not know why my "contain" can't use.

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string searchString)
{
    var movies = from m in _context.Movie
                 select m;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        movies = movies.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(searchString));
    }

    return View(await movies.ToListAsync());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the following code:

In the Index View Page: submit the form to the Index Action via the Get method, and for the search text box, named as `searchString`. For the Search button, use the `submit` type:

```
<form asp-action="Index" method="get">
    <div class="form-actions no-color">
        <p>
            Find by name: <input type="text" name="searchString" value="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]" />
            <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default" /> |
            <a asp-action="Index">Back to Full List</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</form>
```

Then, in the Index action method, you can add break point to check whether the parameter value is correct or not, and check the query result.

the screenshot as below:

[image]

More detail information, you can check [the tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-5.0) and the [sample code](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/main/aspnetcore/data/ef-mvc/intro/samples/cu-final).